# Changing property of controller from directive

Tags: angularjs

EDIT: see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/py5um/2/)

I have a list of items, that I show as text via a directive (all is simplified here, it's more comlicated than just text, but it's the same in principle). Like so:

```
<body ng:controller="BaseController">
    ...
    <div ng:controller="Controller">
        <itemdir ng:repeat="item in items" item="item"></item>
    </div>
    ...
    <input ng:model="currentItem" />
</body>
```

When I click it, it should show the content of the clicked item in an input.

`items` array as well as `currentItem` belong to BaseController scope.

The directive produces a template (see below) with ng:click which should change BaseController scope's property (called currentItem). However it does not do anything to it (input value is not changed to the new current item). In Batarang for Chrome I can see that the currentItem property is visible and changed in the scope of the directive but not of the BaseController.

```
module.directive 'itemdir', () ->
    restrict: 'E'
    replace: true
    template: '<div ng:click="show(item)"></div>'
    controller: 'EditorController'
    scope: 
        item: '=item'
    link: ($scope, $element, $attrs) ->
        update = -> 
                    $element.html($scope.item)

        $scope.$watch('item', update)
```

For changing the property I tried a method `show(item)` which is defined in the BaseController's scope which only assigns the item parameter to $scope.currentItem.

It doesn't work even when I change the ng:click value from `show(item)` to `currentItem = item`

I know this is some scope issue, but it seems I still don't grasp all the details of it.

Comment: would it be possible for you to prepare a jsFiddle / plunker with your simplified example? It looks like it is a scoping issues (as both directive and ngRepeat will create a new scope) but hard to say exactly where the issue is without seeing the running code.

Comment: Link provided in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, looking at the provided jsFiddle we can see that the `BaseController` is being used both in a directive *and* in top div. This introduced a subtle issue since it was possible to invoke the `show(item)` method from top-buttons and HTML produced by directives, but those methods *were invoked on different controllers and writing to different scopes*.

Now, it is hard to deduce from your question if the use of BaseController in a directive was intentional or not (in the question the directive has the EditorController) but assuming that this was by accident and you want to keep BaseController for a div and still invoke methods on it from a directive *you need to take special care when creating isolated scopes* (as the name implies those are really isolated so not inheriting from a parent scope). Basically you need to make sure that the `show` method is available in an isolated scope and points to the right method in the parent scope.

Taking your example you would define your directive like this (please note `show : '&ngClick'`):

```
module.directive('itemdir', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    template:'<div ng:click="show(item)" class="clickable"></div>',
    scope : {item : '=', show : '&ngClick'},
    link:function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $element.html($scope.item)
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/M9B93/

In the future you might find AngularJS Batarang extension for Chrome (http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/introducing-angularjs-batarang.html) useful as it allows to visualize scopes and their content.

Comment: I see, thanks. However, the final directive template is a bit more comlicated and the ng:click is at an element located in some wrapping containers, in that case it doesn't work (I suppose it searches only in the root element?). However, I figured it out, just before you posted (I was actually writing my own answer) - I just removed the whole scope property (with the controller as well, which I tried out of despair). Thanks.